# Permission error running a JAR as non-root user on Docker

Tags: linux, docker, alpine-linux

I did write the following Dockerfiler:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

RUN addgroup -g 999 -S appgroup && \
     adduser -u 999 -S appuser -G appgroup
USER appuser

COPY myapp.jar /usr/app/myapp.jar 

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/usr/app/myapp.jar"]
```

When I run the image, I get the follwing error:

```
main ERROR Unable to create file logs/file.log java.io.IOException: Could not create directory /logs
```

Could you please tell me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 4):

User `appuser` does not have write permissions in the current working directory (`/`, you can verify it with `docker run --rm openjdk:8-jdk-alpine pwd`), and it seems that your application needs to create a `logs/` directory in that working directory.

Possible solutions :

- set the `WORKDIR` to a place he can write (`/tmp` for example, or `/home/appuser` if it is created) in the `Dockerfile`
- you can use option `--workdir /path/to/a/folder/where/appuser/can/write` when issuing `docker run` command
- you can create the `/logs` folder with right permissions (write for `appuser`)